# Jquery Masonry append item issues

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-masonry

I have a backbone fetch view method that does this:

```
var ResultsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template : _.template($("#result_template").html()),
  render : function() {
    this.collection.each(function(result) {
      var $output = $(this.template(result.toJSON()));
      var $container = $('#result_content');
      $container.append($output)
      $container.masonry('appended', $output);
    }, this);
    return this;
  }
});
```

What I am trying to do is for every item in my results collection.... append it to my #result_content div, in the same fashion as can be seen here: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html

The issue here is that the layout is not filled (it's just a single column at the moment. I have to call reload at the end of all of this like so:

```
$container.masonry('reload')
```

Which is not what I want. I want to append from top down.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, just change `$container.append()` to `$container.prepend()`.

Comment: This sort of works, but it waits till ever image is loaded before doing the reload. So it's like.... wait... wait.. wait.. reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change that line to `$container.prepend($output).masonry('reload');` then remove the subsequent line `$container.masonry('appended', $output);` and also don't call "reload" at the end.

Comment: Edit... not quite perfect. I'm not sure I understand what is happening, but the div each image sits in is having its height truncated. So the image sort of sits outside on the bottom bit. I think I need to set a height on the div because Masonry is trying to do it's ordering using the heights the divs have without the image.

Comment: Nevermind I got it. Had to add a reload call when images are loaded

`$output.imagesLoaded( function(){ $container.masonry('reload') });`

Comment: Great job Joe Coder.it was a serious issue from last 5 days.And now its solved by adding $container.prepend($output).masonry('reload'); line.and commenting //$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); .Thanks