# Masonry and infinite scroll append to top

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I am currently using masonry and infinite scroll... is their a way to append the masonry items to appear on top instead of appearing on the bottom?

Comment: Just found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613416/jquery-masonry-append-item-issues